# How to make swiftui scrollview collapse a view by default

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I’m working on a project that let the user pick a data from a calendar view and the app will show the data for that day. I have made a collapsable calendar view that expand by default and the collapse as the user scroll up (The code below). But I want it to collapse at first by the default and then if the user want they can scroll down to expand the calendar.  Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!!

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
  @State private var selectedMonth: Date = .currentMonth
  @State private var selectedDate: Date = .now
  var safeArea: EdgeInsets
  var body: some View {
    let maxHeight = calendarHeight - (calendarTitleViewHeight + weekLabelHeight + safeArea.top + 50 + topPadding + bottomPadding - 50)
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        CalendarView()
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
          ForEach(1...15, id: \.self) { _ in
            CardView()
          }
        }
        .padding(15)

      }
    }
    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    .scrollTargetBehavior(CustomScrollBehaviour(maxHeight: maxHeight))
  }


  @ViewBuilder
  func CardView() -> some View {
    RoundedRectangle (cornerRadius: 15)
      .fill(.blue.gradient)
      .frame(height: 70)
      .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
          Circle()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6, content: {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
              .frame(width: 100, height: 5)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
              .frame(width: 70, height: 5)
          })

        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.25))
        .padding(15)
      }
  }

  @ViewBuilder
  func CalendarView() -> some View {
    GeometryReader {
      let size = $0.size
      let minY = $0.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .vertical)).minY
      let maxHeight = size.height - (calendarTitleViewHeight + weekLabelHeight + safeArea.top + 50 + topPadding + bottomPadding - 50)
      let progress = max(min((-minY / maxHeight), 1), 0)

      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
        Text(currentMonth)
          .font(.system(size: 35 - (10 * progress)))
          .offset(y: -50 * progress)
          .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
          .overlay(alignment: .topLeading, content: {
            GeometryReader {
              let size = $0.size
              Text(year)
                .font(.system(size: 25 - (10 * progress)))
                .offset(x: (size.width + 5) * progress, y: progress * 3)
            }
          })
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
          .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing, content: {
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
              Button("", systemImage: "chevron.left"){
                monthUpdate(false)
              }
              .contentShape(.rect)
              Button("", systemImage: "chevron.right"){
                monthUpdate(true)
              }
              .contentShape(.rect)

            }
            .font(.title3)
            .foregroundStyle(.primary)
            .offset(x: 150 * progress)
          })
          .frame(height: calendarTitleViewHeight)
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
          HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols, id: \.self) { symbol in
              Text(symbol.prefix(3))
                .font(.caption)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)

            }
          }
          .frame(height: weekLabelHeight, alignment: .bottom)

          LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(spacing: 0), count: 7), spacing: 0, content: {
            ForEach(selectedMonthDates) { day in
              Text(day.shortSymbol)
                .foregroundStyle(day.ignored ? .secondary : .primary)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
                  Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                    .opacity(Calendar.current.isDate(day.date, inSameDayAs: selectedDate) ? 1 : 0)
                    .offset(y: progress * -2)
                })
                .contentShape(.rect)
                .onTapGesture {
                  selectedDate = day.date
                }
            }
          })
          .frame(height: calendarGridHeight - ((calendarGridHeight - 50) * progress), alignment: .top)
          .offset(y: (monthProgress * -50) * progress )
          .contentShape(.rect)
          .clipped()
        }
        .offset(y: progress * -50)
      })
      .foregroundStyle(.white)
      .padding(.horizontal, horizontalPadding)
      .padding(.top, topPadding)
      .padding(.top, safeArea.top)
      .padding(.bottom, bottomPadding)
      .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
      .frame(height: size.height - (maxHeight * progress), alignment: .top)
      .background(.red.gradient)
      //Stick to the top
      .clipped()
      .contentShape(.rect)
      .offset(y: -minY)


    }
    .frame(height: calendarHeight)
    .zIndex(1000)

  }

  func format(_ format: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.string(from: selectedMonth)
  }

  func monthUpdate(_ increment: Bool = true) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    guard let month = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: increment ? 1 : -1, to: selectedMonth) else { return }
    guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: increment ? 1 : -1, to: selectedDate) else { return }
    selectedMonth = month
    selectedDate = date
  }

  var selectedMonthDates: [Day] {
    return extractDates(selectedMonth)
  }

  var currentMonth: String {
    return format("MMMM")
  }

  var monthProgress: CGFloat {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    if let index = selectedMonthDates.firstIndex(where: { calendar.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: selectedDate)}) {
      return CGFloat(index/7).rounded()
    }
    return 1.0
  }

  var year: String {
    return format("YYYY")
  }

  var calendarHeight: CGFloat {
    return calendarTitleViewHeight + weekLabelHeight + calendarGridHeight + safeArea.top + topPadding + bottomPadding
  }

  var calendarTitleViewHeight: CGFloat {
    return 75.0
  }

  var weekLabelHeight: CGFloat {
    return 30.0
  }

  var calendarGridHeight: CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(selectedMonthDates.count / 7) * 50
  }

  var horizontalPadding: CGFloat {
    return 15.0
  }

  var topPadding: CGFloat {
    return 15.0
  }

  var bottomPadding: CGFloat {
    return 5.0
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}

struct CustomScrollBehaviour: ScrollTargetBehavior {
  var maxHeight: CGFloat
  func updateTarget(_ target: inout ScrollTarget, context: TargetContext) {
    if target.rect.minY < maxHeight {
      target.rect = .zero
    }
  }
}

extension Date {
  static var currentMonth: Date {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    guard let currentMonth = calendar.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: .now)) else {
      return .now
    }
    return currentMonth
  }
}

extension View {
  func extractDates(_ month: Date) -> [Day] {
    var days: [Day] = []
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"

    guard let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: month)?.compactMap({ value -> Date? in
      return calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: value - 1, to: month)
    }) else {
      return days
    }

    let firstWeekDay = calendar.component(.weekday, from: range.first!)

    for index in Array(0..<firstWeekDay-1).reversed() {
      guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -index - 1, to: range.first!) else { return days}
      let shortSymbol = formatter.string(from: date)
      days.append(.init(shortSymbol: shortSymbol, date: date, ignored: true))
    }

    range.forEach { date in
      let shortSymbol = formatter.string(from: date)
      days.append(.init(shortSymbol: shortSymbol, date: date))
    }

    let lastWeekDay = 7 - calendar.component(.weekday, from: range.last!)

    if lastWeekDay > 0 {
      for index in 0..<lastWeekDay {
        guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: index + 1, to: range.last!) else { return days}
        let shortSymbol = formatter.string(from: date)
        days.append(.init(shortSymbol: shortSymbol, date: date, ignored: true))
      }
    }


    return days
  }

}

struct Day: Identifiable {
  var id: UUID = .init()
  var shortSymbol: String
  var date: Date
  var ignored: Bool = false
}
```

I have tried to user the `.defaultScrollAnchor(.init(x: 0, y: maxHeight/totalHeight))` but I couldn’t figure out the totalHeight of the scrollView. Could you guys please tell me how to use this attribute and make it to work?